# How can I update my Visual Studio solution so that it uses WPF 4.0?

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2010

I recently converted my solution from Visual Studio 2008 to 2010, hoping I would be able to use WPF 4.0's SelectionBrush property.  I try to access this property in the XAML for my project as follows:

```
<TextBox SelectionBrush="Aqua"/>
```

Disappointingly, It underlines my code and says: The property 'SelectionBrush' was not found in type 'TextBox'.  If I create a new Visual Studio 2010 project, I DO have access to this property within that project, so it is not an issue with Visual Studio 2010.  How can I specify that I want to use WPF 4.0 with my newly converted project?

Thanks,

Dalal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the project and go to the properties.  Once in there you will need to modify the settings for it to target the ".NET Framework 4.0" option.